# What does <> mean in excel?

Tags: excel

Google doesn't understand <> so that failed thus asking here.

What does '<>' (less than followed by greater than) mean in Excel? For example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E37:N37>0)*(E37:N37<>"")*(E37:N37))
```

What's happening here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means "not equal to" (as in, the values in cells E37-N37 are not equal to `""`, or in other words, they are not empty.)